# How can I create single-thread coroutine context under Common pool in Kotlin?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, threadpool, kotlin-coroutines

Short requirement: have ability to create corotine context, which will executed in the single thread only (e.g. without parallelism).

Additional requirement: it is better to use existing CommonPool (e.g. Thread Pool) for these tasks

Actually kotlin coroutines have method `newSingleThreadContext` which will create separate thread and schedule all tasks into it. However, this is dedicated thread, so ~1000 such contexts will require a lot of resources.

Therefore, I'd like to have context with the following characteristics:

- Maximum one task can be executed at the same time
- This context should reuse any other (e.g. parent context). E.g context should hold no additional threads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from the [`1.6.0`](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/introducing-kotlinx-coroutines-1-6-0/#dispatcher-views-api) version of the `kotlinx.coroutines` library we can use [`limitedParallelism`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/limited-parallelism.html?query=open%20fun%20limitedParallelism(parallelism:%20Int):%20CoroutineDispatcher) function on the [`CoroutineDispatcher`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/index.html) object, which lets you limit parallelism without creating additional thread pools and provides a unified way to create dispatchers for unbound parallelism.

Example of usage:

```
class UserRepository {
    private val dbDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(1)

    suspend fun getUserById(userId: Int): User? = withContext(dbDispatcher) {
        executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1", userId).singleOrNull()
   }
}
```

`limitedParallelism(1)` guarantees the parallelism restriction - at most 1 coroutine can be executed concurrently in this dispatcher.

It should solve the problem:

> Maximum one task can be executed at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

When you say, for example `withSerialContext(Dispatchers.Default) {doWork()}`, it executes `doWork()` on a default dispatcher thread, but all of its parts will execute one at a time like they do in runBlocking{}.   Note that even though it's one thread at a time, there is no guarantee that it will be the same thread for the whole operation.

```
suspend fun <T> withSerialContext(
        context: CoroutineDispatcher,
        block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): T = withContext(SerialContextDispatcher(context), block)

private class SerialContextDispatcher(private val target: CoroutineDispatcher) : CoroutineDispatcher() {

    private val q = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>()
    //Whoever CASes this false->true schedules execution of runproc
    private val pending = AtomicBoolean(false)
    //Only one of these runs at a time
    private val runproc = object: Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            while(true) {
                val proc = q.poll();
                if (proc != null) {
                    try {
                        proc.run()
                    }
                    catch (e: Throwable) {
                        target.dispatch(EmptyCoroutineContext, this)
                        throw e
                    }
                } else {
                    pending.set(false);
                    if (q.isEmpty() || !pending.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        q.add(block)
        if (pending.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            target.dispatch(EmptyCoroutineContext, runproc)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation blocks a default dispatcher thread while there is work which can block other coroutines from running. There is also a race condition, if dispatch runs between `val proc = q.poll();` and `pending.set(false);` then the block will be left on the queue.

Comment: The default dispatcher thread isn't blocked when it's not busy.  runproc returns when it finds the q empty.  Also there is no race condition.  If there is a dispatch after poll(), then after pending.set(false), q.isEmpty() will be false and the loop will continue to execute the dispatched work

Comment: Oh, you're talking about fairness w.r.t. the dispatcher thread...  I actually like this better than sending a task to the back of the line every time it suspends, since it works out better for the kinds of loads I have in mind, but it's easy to modify to reschedule between each task if you like.

Comment: Yeah, looks like my race condition statement was wrong, sorry (wish I could edit and strike through the original comment).

Answer (score 0):

I found, that there are not simple solution to create such context.

There is open issue on githuib - https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/261

I think I will update this question when I find right solution.